# Google Analytics Site Content Showing Wrong URls

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My Google Analytics properties are showing wrong urls in the site content section. For example my website url is https://www.olaywall.com/au but in Google analytics site content, the urls are showing https://www.olaywall.com/au//au/ for all web pages. Same thing is happening in my other google analytics properties.

Comment: Is this a coding question about the Google Analytics API or about the Google Analytics website (their web app/dashboard)?

Comment: GA usually reports page paths, not full urls. Do you have by chance a filter that adds the hostname to your page paths ? It might be that this is slightly misconfigured and adds the full url to the path.

Comment: No i dont have any filter that adds the hostname @EikePierstorff. My website url is https://www.olaywall.com/au/ and Google analytics is showing the data for https://www.olaywall.com/au//au/. I dont have any clue where is the URL is comes from.